# A useful condition ensuring equivalency of metrics

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I obtained a useful condition ensuring when two metrics generate the same topology, but for sake of confidence I post it here to see if this is correct.

“Suppose $d_1,d_2$ are metrics on a set $X$ and suppose there are positive constants $D,c,C$ such that $d_1(x,y)\leq D$ implies $cd_1(x,y)\leq d_2(x,y)\leq Cd_1(x,y)$. Then the topology generated by $d_2$ is contained in the topology generated by $d_1$. By symmetry, reversing the order of $d_1$ and $d_2$ gives a condition implying the reverse inclusion.” Is this claim right? This idea is from the textbook *Elementary Topology, Problem Textbook*.

If it is right, for example we can readily check that for any metric $d$, the two metrics $d$ and $d/(1+d)$ are equivalent.

Comment: Yes. When these conditions are met then $d_1,d_2$ are called uniformly equivalent (a.k.a. strongly equivalent).  But if $d$ is an unbounded metric then $d$ is equivalent to $d'=d/(1+d)$ and also to $d''=\min (1,d)$ but $d$ is not uniformly equivalent to $d'$ nor to $d''$ because they are bounded but $d$ is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that's correct. Can you prove it?

You can also show the following, which is, I think, commonly used to show that two metrics induce the same topology (at least in all the exercises or other situations I met).

> Let $d_1$ and $d_2$ be two metrics on a nonempty set $X$.
>
> Suppose that there exists $\alpha,\beta>0$ such that $$\forall x,y\in X,\alpha d_1(x,y)\le d_2(x,y)\le\beta d_1(x,y).$$
>
> Then $d_1$ and $d_2$ induce the same topology on $X$.

Comment: I already proved it, just wanted to make sure the claim is correct.

Comment: Great! Well done!

Comment: The proposition that you have mentioned is a commonly used fact but is weaker than the proposition stated in my question

Comment: You're right. Indeed the mentioned proposition implies the one in your question.